# Keras Data Augmentation (BreakHis)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My problem is to amplify the BreakHis dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/ambarish/breakhis) using the following instructions:

**We chose the DC subclass as the baselihne, and amplified each of the remaining sublclasses by turning images up and down, left and right, and using counterclowise rotatiotion of 90 ° and 180 °.**

Which instructions should I write in Keras to perform the data augmentation? Obviously, I would like to understand how to do those operations in general.

This is the distribution of the original dataset:
[image: Original dataset]

This is the distribution of the augmented dataset:
[image: Augmented dataset]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function will apply wanted operations with equal probability, if you want to apply more than 1 operation for an array you can alter the code. We provide the number of augmentations to the code as augmentation_number and the image array. Then this function applies transformations on it.

```
import random
import numpy as np
 
def generate_rotated(array,augmentation_number):
    m=0
    All=[]
    while m!=augmentation_number:
        rand=random.random()    
        if rand<=0.25:
            Array=np.rot90(array)
        elif 0.25<rand and rand<=0.5:
            Array=np.rot90(array,2)
        elif 0.5<rand and rand<=0.75:
            Array=np.flipud(array)
        else:
            Array=np.fliplr(array)
        All.append(Array)
        m+=1
    AugmentedArrays=np.array(All)
    return AugmentedArrays
```

Edit function:
-Also if you want to implement a function with %50 probability you can create it like this:

```
def generate_rotated(array,augmentation_number):
    m=0
    All=[]
    while m!=augmentation_number:
        rand=random.random()    
        if rand<0.5:
            Array=np.rot90(array)
        rand=random.random()    
        if rand<0.5:
            Array=np.rot90(array,2)
        rand=random.random()    
        if rand<0.5:
            Array=np.flipud(array) 
        rand=random.random()    
        if rand<0.5:
            Array=np.fliplr(array)
        All.append(Array)
        m+=1
    AugmentedArrays=np.array(All)
    return AugmentedArrays
```

Example using:

```
array=np.array([[12,323,2332],[2323,23452,5195],[95310,450,3]])
```

[image]

```
generate_rotated(array,5).shape=(5, 3, 3)

generate_rotated(array,5)
```

[image]

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes I need 90 and 180 counterclockwise and rotations up and down, left and right. Could you write me all these operations as requested? Thanks in advance, you'd be very kind.

Comment: I also want to understand if I need to implement different generators for each operation or if these operations can all be implemented in one generator. The goal is to get the same number of augmented data as the example.

Comment: The thing is augmentation in the dataset that you've provided doesn't follow a specific pattern while some of them augmented n times while others m times. For example, 40x row A column augmented 7 times 114-->798 while F column in the same row augmented 3times 253-->759. Can you elaborate on what you want a little bit more?

Comment: This is true. Specifically, suppose we consider column A which has increased 7 times (114 * 7 = 798). What instructions do I have to write in Keras to achieve this and consider: rotations up and down, left and right and using counterclockwise rotations of 90 and 180 °? I thank you infinitely.

Comment: There are multiple possible solutions for this but first, let's be clear that we are on the same page.  Do you mean up-down, left-right rotation as a horizontal and vertical flip?  And do you want counterclockwise 90&180* rotation as discrete rotations which means not any rotation between the range 0-180?

Comment: Exactly, up-down, left-right rotation as a horizontal and vertical flip and counterclockwise 90 & 180 * rotation as discrete rotations.

Comment: I've edited the code. You can provide the augmentation number by getting it from your df by dividing the second df matrix with the first one.

Comment: In this way different images will be the same! Perhaps it is not correct from the augmenting point of view, we should make sure that all the images are different.

Comment: Couldn't understand what you meant by "In this way different images will be the same!"